# html && CSS - dropdown menu doesn't appear

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

my dropdown menu doesn't appear, could somebody help me please?
It should appear under "Interno" but when I click on it nothing appears!
I've found this menu on internet and I tried to use it, but seems I'm wrong
Full project here(the code is too long): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6769AiSruENc0xWTm5IVlY5NDQ/view?usp=sharing

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sito della Cattedrale di San Cataldo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="asubtleorange.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stili/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stili/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="page"> 
    <div id="header">
        <div class="title">CATTEDRALE DI SAN CATALDO</div>
     </div>
    <div id="bar">
        <div class="menuLink"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div>
        <div class="menuLink"><a href="storia.html">Storia</a></div>
        <div class="menuLink"><a href="esterno.php">Esterno</a></div>
        <div class="menuLink"><a href="#">Interno</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">In Cinemas Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">On DVD/Blu-ray</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Showtimes &amp; Tickets</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pageContent">

    <div class="articleTitle">L'esterno della Cattedrale</div>


      <div class="articleContent">


         <div class="item-page"  style="text-align:center;">
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider"  style="margin:auto;">
<img src="images/esterno/esterno01.jpg" alt=""  style="background-color:#333333;"/>
<img src="images/esterno/esterno02.jpg" alt=""style="background-color:#333333;"/>
<img src="images/esterno/esterno03.jpg" alt=""style="background-color:#333333;"/>
<img src="images/esterno/esterno04.jpg" alt="" style="background-color:#333333;"/>
<img src="images/esterno/esterno05.jpg" alt="" style="background-color:#333333;"/>
<img src="images/esterno/esterno06.jpg" alt="" style="background-color:#333333;"/>
<img src="images/esterno/esterno07.jpg" alt=""style="background-color:#333333;"/>
<img src="images/esterno/esterno08.jpg" alt=""style="background-color:#333333;"/>
<img src="images/esterno/esterno09.jpg" alt="" style="background-color:#333333;"/>
<img src="images/esterno/esterno10.jpg" alt=""style="background-color:#333333;"/>
<img src="images/esterno/esterno11.jpg" alt=""style="background-color:#333333;"/>
</div>
     <p>bla bla bla</p>
 </div></div></div> </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#slider').nivoSlider({
  effect:'fade',
  pauseTime: 5000
  });
});

function PNGManagement1 () {
      setTimeout (function(){
      $('.nivoSlider .nivo-main-image').animate({opacity:0},500)
      },20);
}
function PNGManagement2 () {
      setTimeout (function(){
      $('.nivoSlider .nivo-main-image').css({opacity:1});
      },20);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

.css

```
/*============================*/
/*=== Stili per lo slider ===*/
/*============================*/
#slider {
    border: 0px solid #333;
    width:640px;
    height:427px;
    margin:40px auto;
    background:url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
#slider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
#slider a {
    border:0;
    display:block;
}

.nivo-controlNav {
    position:absolute;
    left:260px;
    bottom:-42px;
}
.nivo-controlNav a {
    display:block;
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    background:url(../images/bullets.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
    margin-right:3px;
    float:left;
}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    background-position:0 -22px;
}

.nivo-directionNav a {
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:url(../images/arrows.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
}
a.nivo-nextNav {
    background-position:-30px 0;
    right:-40px;
}
a.nivo-prevNav {
    left:-40px;
}

.nivo-caption {
    text-shadow:none;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.nivo-caption a { 
    color:#efe9d1;
    text-decoration:underline;
}






/*----- Menu Outline -----*/
.menu-wrap {
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#3e3436;
}

.menu {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0px auto;
}

.menu li {
    margin:0px;
    list-style:none;
    font-family:'Ek Mukta';
}

.menu a {
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    color:#919191;
}

.menu li:hover > a, .menu .current-item > a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#be5b70;
}

.menu .arrow {
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0%;
}

/*----- Top Level -----*/
.menu > ul > li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    font-size:19px;
}

.menu > ul > li > a {
    padding:10px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.menu > ul > li:hover > a, .menu > ul > .current-item > a {
    background:#2e2728;
}

/*----- Bottom Level -----*/
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index:1;
    opacity:1;
}

.sub-menu {
    width:160%;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0px;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity linear 0.15s;
    box-shadow:0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background:#2e2728;
}

.sub-menu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:16px;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    padding:10px 30px;
    display:block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover, .sub-menu .current-item a {
    background:#3e3436;
}
```

Comment: Your probably going to need the actual to provide a demo of this not-working **including the associated javascript files**.

Comment: @Paulie_D sorry but it was too long, I linked the full code in the first post

Comment: Could you try to make a JSFiddle with your nav?

Comment: The demo should also contain **just enough** code to reproduce the problem **and no more!** We don't need the whole page...just the menu.

Comment: @ChrisG check this: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=KKSanAi54p

Comment: Your CSS is completely wrong. All your menu tags in your css file are wrong. Menu is nowhere to be seen in your html, it's called BAR. So this can't work what so ever man.

Comment: oh, I think this is why I tried to add the dropdown menu in the template original menu :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a JSFiddle with your nav working.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisG87/ok609zp6/)

I now added:

```
.menuLink:hover ul {
display: block;
}
```

Aswell as making your UL sub-menu display none to start.
Then, when you hover your ul, it shows and the following code makes it stay:

```
.menu-link:active {
display: block;
}
```

This should give you a solid start to making it your own!